# @Injectable() decorator and providers array

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services, angular-module

Does a service that is provided in "root" within the @Injectable() decorator still have to be in the providers array of the module?

The [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) doesn't really give me an answer or I don't quite understand it.

Inside my core folder I have a authentication service which is provided in root. I wan't to import my core module inside the app module in order to use all the services and components provided.

Do I have to additionally set up the service in the providers array of the module, or is it enough that it is already provided at root level using the decorator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bullet points in the link you provided are all different methods of registering services, from the least specific to most specific.

App-specific - use `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`

> When you provide the service at the root level, Angular creates a single, shared instance of HeroService and injects it into any class that asks for it. Registering the provider in the @Injectable() metadata also allows Angular to optimize an app by removing the service from the compiled app if it isn't used.

Module-specific - register in module providers

> When you register a provider with a specific NgModule, the same instance of a service is available to all components in that NgModule. To register at this level, use the providers property of the @NgModule() decorator,

Component-specific - register in component

> When you register a provider at the component level, you get a new instance of the service with each new instance of that component. At the component level, register a service provider in the providers property of the @Component() metadata.

All quotes above are from the official [Introduction to services and dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) page

- If you only have one module, then the first two methods are equivalent and only need to use one method. It's easier to go with `@Injectable` - the default CLI approach.
- If you want to share service instances between multiple modules, use the first method.
- If you want one instance per independent module, use the second approach.
- If you want to share an app-wide instance with all components except one, then use the first approach in addition to the third approach for the one anomalous component.

It is my opinion that most use cases would fall into the first two approaches.

### Registering module-specific services

Tip: just use `providedIn: 'root'`. Unused services won't be compiled for a module if it isn't used due to tree shaking. Declaring module-specific services seems redundant and, as we shall see, can cause problems.

There are two ways to register module-specific services - either from the module or from the service.

module

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

service

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: MyModule })
```

The latter is the officially recommended approach. Declaring the providers array is a hangover from the earlier days.

From [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/providers):

> The example above shows the preferred way to provide a service in a module. This method is preferred because it enables tree-shaking of the service if nothing injects it. If it's not possible to specify in the service which module should provide it, you can also declare a provider for the service within the module

### Why you should just use `providedIn: 'root'`

So we see that this approach is tree-shakeable. So far so good. But you will end up with circular references if you simply try to import the same module that the components consuming the clients are declared in.

Take this setup:

my-module

```
declarations: [
  MyComponent
]
```

my-service

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: MyModule })
```

my-component

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
```

- my-service imports my-module
- my-module imports my-component
- my-component imports my-service

There is a circular dependency.

The workaround for this is to create a service module and import that into your module.

my-module

```
imports: [
  MyModuleServices
],
declarations: [
  MyComponent
]
```

my-module-services

my-service

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: MyModuleServices })
```

my-component

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
```

This is a very long-winded alternative to simply using `providedIn: 'root'` and letting the tree shaking do the work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. That definitely makes it clearer and more understandable for me. However, I still have a question. There is still the possibility to set the service in the @injectable() decorator like this: @incectable ({ providedIn: 'SpecificComponentOrModule' }). Is this approach equivalent to the approach where you set the service in the providers array of the module or anything special?

Comment: Interesting. I've never used `providedIn` for anything other than `'root'`. It's interesting that the official guide for setting up a module-specific service is via `providedIn: MyModule`, which is equivalent to adding the service as a provider to the module. You would get a circular reference if you tried to do that with components though.

Comment: I've appended my answer with the module-specific service details.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I think it is a perfect answer to the question now. There are probably several ways that should be considered carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the deep explanation. I have a case that I don't think it has been covered, though: a service that is defined in a lazy-loaded module and whose scope is the module only. Apparently the use of providedIn: LazyLoadedModule with a component that has the service injected causes circular dependency, but I don't like the fix being let the service be available at root scope

Answer (score 2):

> Does a service that is provided in "root" within the @Injectable()
>   decorator still have to be in the providers array of the module?

No!

When you create a service with the Angular CLI I believe that the `providedIn: "root"` is added by default, so technically you do not ever need to add one of your own services into a providers array.

> Do I have to additionally set up the service in the providers array of
>   the module, or is it enough that it is already provided at root level
>   using the decorator?

It should be enough that it is provided at the root level using the decorator.

However, not all of the services I create are intended to be global.  It is not uncommon for me to remove the configuration object to the `@Injectable()`metadata when I am creating a service that will be shared among a single screen or sub module--not across the full application.In such a case I will have to add that service to a providers array on the respective components that use it or sub module declaration.