# in angular, Circular dependency when using providedIn and forRoot

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lazy-loading, tree-shaking

I am developing an angular library. it has an internal service. which is defined like below.
Used `providedIn` to be tree-shakable. and didn't use `providedIn:'root'` because its internal and just used in the module scope.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: MyChartModule,
})
export class LineChartLibService {
```

and when i wanted to add `forRoot` in module definition to have just one instance in lazy loading, it encounter Circular dependency.

```
export class MyChartModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyChartModule,
      providers: [LineChartLibService],
    };
  }
}
```

what should we do in this situations?
is it possible to have a lazy load-able tree-shakable service in library?

```
WARNING: Circular dependency: dist\my-chart\esm2015\lib\my-chart.module.js -> dist\my-chart\esm2015\lib\line-chart\line-chart.component.js 
-> dist\my-chart\esm2015\lib\line-chart-lib.service.js -> dist\my-chart\esm2015\lib\my-chart.module.js
```

Comment: Can you paste circular path here?

Comment: @GouravGarg. Edited question and added the warning.

Comment: Please add the entire module code as it seems that there should also be a line-chart.component.js which we cannot see here.

Comment: When you are adding this to providers:[] then why you assigning providedIn to that?

Comment: @GouravGarg for it to be tree-shakable and for those whom didn't call forRoot.(it's a library and you don't know where it will be used)

Comment: If you are making part of providers in forRoot then this tree-shakable feature is not applicable anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have previously answered a (non-duplicate) question that provides you with alternatives to this approach.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60377431/5367916

Take this setup:

**my-module.ts**

```
declarations: [
  MyComponent
]
```

**my-service.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: MyModule })
```

**my-component.ts**

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
```

- my-service imports my-module
- my-module imports my-component
- my-component imports my-service

There is a circular dependency.

#### A workaround

The workaround for this is to create a service module and import that into your module.

**my-module.ts**

```
imports: [
  MyModuleServices
],
declarations: [
  MyComponent
]
```

**my-module-services.ts**

```
// no imports or declarations
```

**my-service.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: MyModuleServices })
```

**my-component.ts**

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
```

#### Alternative

The much more straightforward way is to add the service to your module's providers.

```js
@NgModule({
  providers: [ MyService ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what happens is the following:

1. You have the line-chart.component.js that probably calls for the LineChartLibService.
2. Within the LineChartLibService you say that this Injectable is provided in MyChartModule.
3. Within the MyChartModule you probably declare the line-chart.component.js to be part of this module.

This means the module asks for the component, which asks for the service, which asks for the module which then asks for the component again: A circular dependency.

If you add more code and context to your question, we might be able to make a better suggestion ;-)